# JSON parsing [`jq`]: Get value of grandparent’s sibling

Tags: json, jq, tree-traversal

#### Example

```
{
  "gp_sibling": "desired_value",
  "grand-parent": {
    "parent": [
      {
        "key": "known_value",
        "sibling": "asdf"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Problem definition

I have a large JSON. I know that `key` has a unique value. I need to get it’s grand-parent’s sibling key value (the value of `gp_sibling` key).

Now, I could `grep` the JSON, but I’d like to use `jq`. But I don’t know to achieve this (I use `jq` for simple queries only).

#### Notes

Although I know that `jq` can be used on Windows too, I use it on Linux only.

#### Post updates

1. Removed commas from the example. Some formatting fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the element `gb_sibling`, you could use the following:

```
jq .gp_sibling <file>
```

If you want to get it only if there is the `key` element with it's value, you could try this:

```
jq 'select(."grand-parent"?.parent?[]?.key=="known_value")|.gp_sibling' <file>
```

This, it filters the elements where the content of the attribute `key` inside `parent` inside `grand-parent` equals `known_value`.

From that result, `gp_sibling` is selected.

[**NOTE**]

`grand-parent` is quoted because the dash would cause problems otherwise.

Comment: I think he would like to extract the value of gp_sibling. | jq '.gp_sibling' | should be enough (tested here https://jqplay.org/#)

Comment: @MarcoMassetti You're right. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Perfect! @dan1st, your solution works with the provided example, but I cannot make it work with the original key names ([example #2](https://jqplay.org/s/2VOZHwNn10)). There is an error: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`. Can you help me out here please?

Comment: @tukusejssirs this is because of the web UI. You should only put the thing inside the `'...'` in `filter`, not the whole command.

Comment: Okay. I had blank output with the non-disclosed data until I added `.[]` (I missed that that whole data was square-bracketed). So in in the end, I used `[some_command] | jq -r '.[] | select(."grand-parent"?.parent?[]?.key=="known_value") | .gp_sibling'`

Comment: Yes, everything works now as expected. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Great @dan1st :)

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the question is that none of the key names except "key" is to be used in the query, and that if there were more than one "grand-parent sibling" that was a string, we'd want them all.

```
paths(.key? == "known_value") as $p
| getpath($p[0:-4])
| .[]
| select(type=="string")
```